# schmidt coefficients are the square root of the eigenvalue of the two partial trace of a density matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, schmidt-decomposition

Let $\psi\rangle_{AB} = \sum_{i=1}^{d}\lambda_{i}|i_{A}\rangle |i_{B}\rangle$ be a state vector of a pure bipartite syste.

Now, $\rho_{AB} = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi| = \sum_{i=1}^{d} \lambda_{i}^{2}|i_{A}\rangle\langle i_{A}| \otimes |i_{B}\rangle \langle i_{B}|$.

The reduced density operator for A, B is $\rho^{A} = \sum_{i=1}^{d}\lambda_{i}^{2}|i_{A}\rangle\langle i_{A}| , \rho^{B} = \sum_{i=1}^{d}\lambda_{i}^{2}|i_{B}\rangle\langle i_{B}|$

Suppose the set of eigenvalues for $\rho^{A}$, $\rho^{B}$ is $S_{A} = {\lambda_{1}^{2}, ...}$, $S_{B} = {\lambda_{1}^{2}, ...}$.

> The schmidt coefficients are the square root of the eigenvalue of the two partial trace? [1]

What does the above mean? Is the below accurate?

> $\lambda_{i} = \sqrt{\lambda_{i}^{2}}$?

[1] [https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/bipartite-states-and-schmidt-decomposition#:~:text=The%20Schmidt%20coefficients%20%E2%88%9A~%CF%87,zero%20have%20the%20same%20multiplicity](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/bipartite-states-and-schmidt-decomposition#:%7E:text=The%20Schmidt%20coefficients%20%E2%88%9A%7E%CF%87,zero%20have%20the%20same%20multiplicity).

Comment: Careful! $\rho_{AB}=\sum_{i,j}\lambda_i\lambda_j|i\rangle\langle j|\otimes|i\rangle\langle j|$.

Comment: @DaftWullie More correctly: $\lambda_{i} = \sqrt{\lambda_{i}\lambda_{j}}$?

Comment: no because you still have to take the partial trace, which returns the same as you had before.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're saying. Could you be more verbose?

My understanding of the theorem is this: determine the eigenvalues for $\rho^{A}\rho^{B}$. Then for each $\xi$ eigenvalue in the set of eigenvalues, take the square root of the $\xi$ eigenvalue.

Comment: I'm not trying to say anything about the theorem (I don't really understand the question, since you seem to state the answer, modulo some being careful about the existence of 0 answers). I'm just saying that the second line of your question is incorrect, although the third line is still correct.

Comment: Thank you @DaftWullie. Yes, the second line is faulty. I've readjusted my workings to this end.